# AngularJS : ng-model not binding two ways when inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have read some posts here on so regarding this subject but all the answers and all of the fiddles I saw not one working properly. I got my plunkr to bind one-way from the dynamically generated field bound through ng-model inside an directive isolated scope to the form in the parent. However is does not bind from the form back to the directive. My initial values are disregarded, so are the changes I make inside the parent scope and I would really like a solution. Here's a code fragment.

```
        <div ng-repeat="field in fields">
            <app-field field="field" ng-model="selected[field.name]" form="form"></app-field>
        </div>

...     
            .directive("appField", function($http, $compile) {
                return {
                    restrict: "AE",
                    scope: {
                        field: "=",
                        ngModel: "=",
                        form: "="
                    },
                    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
                        $http.get("field.html").then(function (result) {
                            element.html(result.data);
                            $compile(element.contents())($scope);
                        });
                    }
                }
           })
```

Here's my fiddle:  http://plnkr.co/edit/ZzC4jS9M9Ev5i6gxUVxB?p=preview

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the directive declaration object property is `scope`, not `$scope` (not to mention that you have both there)

Comment: yeah darn plunkrs, copy and paste error. That's what you get when you push all the buttons and pull all the levers in hopes of something sticking ;) but tx ... still not working though ...

Comment: Seems to be working for me: http://plnkr.co/edit/VaB0KvaESQAmolrlY1ui?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property is `scope`, not `$scope`. Then, remove the `scope:false` and you are done!

Also, you can use the `templateUrl` property instead of `link` (in this case):

```
.directive("appField", function($http, $compile) {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            scope: {
                field: "=",
                ngModel: "=",
                form: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'field.html'
        }
})
```

Comment: And you can see it in action here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DmmL4c2HqlXI1WN8EqEy?p=preview